# Inverted ROC curve

Tags: r, roc

I am using tidymodels package in R. Running random forest to classify three classes. There are about 8000 samples in total and 130 features. This is how the ROC curves look like.

[image]

The predictions for all 3 classes are actually pretty good and fit with expectations. The misclassified samples are also easy to explain. Here are some metrics as given by the software on test data:

```
  .metric      .estimate
1 accuracy         0.887
2 bal_accuracy     0.917
3 f_meas           0.887
4 kap              0.831
5 mcc              0.835
6 precision        0.895
7 recall           0.889
8 roc_auc          0.975
```

And the confusion matrix.

```
           Truth
Prediction A     B      C
A          573   19     22
B          6     662    17
C          148   25     628
```

Everything seems to be fine except for the strange ROC curves. I am trying to find an explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have figured this out. It was to do with the order of prediction classes provided to `roc_curve()`. Here is a reproducible example below.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(dplyr)

dfr <- iris %>% mutate(Species=factor(Species))

data_split <- initial_split(dfr,prop=0.70,strata=Species)
data_train <- training(data_split)
data_test <- testing(data_split)
data_tune_cv <- vfold_cv(data_train,v=10,repeats=1,strata=Species)
recipe <- data_train %>% recipe(Species ~ .) 

rf_spec <- rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", num.threads = (parallel::detectCores()-1), importance = "impurity") 

rf_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(recipe) %>%
  add_model(rf_spec)

rf_metrics <- metric_set(roc_auc,accuracy,bal_accuracy,f_meas,kap,mcc,precision,recall)

rf_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(mtry=finalize(mtry(),data_train), min_n(), trees(), size=20)
rf_tune <- tune_grid(rf_wf, resamples=data_tune_cv, grid=rf_grid)
#> ! Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
rf_best <- select_best(rf_tune,metric="roc_auc")

rf_training_pred <- rf_wf %>%
  finalize_workflow(rf_best) %>%
  fit_resamples(data_tune_cv,control = control_grid(save_pred=TRUE)) %>% 
  collect_predictions() 
#> ! Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold02: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold03: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold04: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold05: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold06: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold07: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold08: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold09: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
#> ! Fold10: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: 5 columns were requested but there were 4 predictors in the data. 4 will...
```

This gives incorrect ROC.

```r
rf_training_pred %>%
  roc_curve(truth=Species,.pred_setosa,.pred_virginica,.pred_versicolor) %>%
  autoplot(rf_training_roc)
```

[image]

This gives the correct ROC.

```r
rf_training_pred %>%
  roc_curve(truth=Species,.pred_setosa,.pred_versicolor,.pred_virginica) %>%
  autoplot(rf_training_roc)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language en_GB:en
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Stockholm
#>  date     2022-09-22
#>  pandoc   2.18 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat     0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  backports      1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  broom        * 1.0.0      2022-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  class          7.3-20     2022-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  cli            3.3.0      2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  codetools      0.2-18     2020-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  colorspace     2.0-3      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  crayon         1.5.1      2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  curl           4.3.2      2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  DBI            1.1.3      2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  dials        * 1.0.0      2022-06-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  DiceDesign     1.9        2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  digest         0.6.29     2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  dplyr        * 1.0.9      2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  ellipsis       0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  evaluate       0.16       2022-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fansi          1.0.3      2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  farver         2.1.1      2022-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fastmap        1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  foreach        1.5.2      2022-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fs             1.5.2      2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  furrr          0.3.1      2022-08-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  future         1.27.0     2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  future.apply   1.9.0      2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  generics       0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  ggplot2      * 3.3.6      2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  globals        0.16.0     2022-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  glue           1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  gower          1.0.0      2022-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  GPfit          1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  gtable         0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  hardhat        1.2.0      2022-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  highr          0.9        2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  htmltools      0.5.3      2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  httr           1.4.3      2022-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  infer        * 1.0.3      2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  ipred          0.9-13     2022-06-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  iterators      1.0.14     2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  knitr          1.39       2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  labeling       0.4.2      2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lattice        0.20-45    2021-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lava           1.6.10     2021-09-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lhs            1.1.5      2022-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lifecycle      1.0.1      2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  listenv        0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lubridate      1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  magrittr       2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  MASS           7.3-58.1   2022-08-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  Matrix         1.4-1      2022-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  mime           0.12       2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  modeldata    * 1.0.1      2022-09-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  munsell        0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  nnet           7.3-17     2022-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  parallelly     1.32.1     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  parsnip      * 1.0.1      2022-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  pillar         1.8.0      2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  prodlim        2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  purrr        * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.cache        0.16.0     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.methodsS3    1.8.2      2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.oo           1.25.0     2022-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.utils        2.12.0     2022-06-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R6             2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  ranger       * 0.14.1     2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  Rcpp           1.0.9      2022-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  recipes      * 1.0.1      2022-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  reprex         2.0.1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rlang          1.0.4      2022-07-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rmarkdown      2.14       2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rpart          4.1.16     2022-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rsample      * 1.1.0      2022-08-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rstudioapi     0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  scales       * 1.2.0      2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  sessioninfo    1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  stringi        1.7.8      2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  stringr        1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  styler         1.7.0      2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  survival       3.4-0      2022-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tibble       * 3.1.8      2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tidymodels   * 1.0.0      2022-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tidyr        * 1.2.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tidyselect     1.1.2      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  timeDate       4021.104   2022-07-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tune         * 1.0.0      2022-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  utf8           1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  vctrs          0.4.1      2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  withr          2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  workflows    * 1.0.0      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  workflowsets * 1.0.0      2022-07-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  xfun           0.32       2022-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  xml2           1.3.3      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  yaml           2.3.5      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  yardstick    * 1.1.0      2022-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#> 
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Hi, great answer. One minor edition: the parameter is prop instead of prob. Thank your for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen if either the predicted or the gold labels (but not both) have been reversed. For example the instances predicted as positive are interpreted as negative by the ROC function, and vice versa. This gives an exact mirror of the real curve from the diagonal, making it look as if the classifier is doing worse than random. You certainly have a bug somewhere, maybe some implicit type conversion which reverses the classes? (R does unintuitive things sometimes!).

Also the fact that the third curve looks good could help you: there must be a difference in the code between the first two and this one.

Answer (score 0):

An inverted ROC curve may be caused by `yardstick`'s assumption that the event is indicated by the first factor level. Setting the following option provides a solution:

```
options(yardstick.event_first = FALSE)

rf_training_pred %>%
roc_curve(truth=Species,.pred_setosa,.pred_versicolor,.pred_virginica) %>%
autoplot(rf_training_roc)
```

Alternatively, you could set the `event_level` argument in the `roc_curve` function to "second"

See: https://github.com/tidymodels/yardstick/issues/94